# Base64 encoded or classic url when displaying a light image many times into a single web page

Tags: html

I have a single 3.3ko image that i display in 15 different `img HTML balise` in my web page.

I am wondering if the Base64 encoded method is not a bad idea for this use case, since it significantly make the page heavier to load (since i display the image 15 times), than using a "classic URL".

However i am not sure that a bigger HTML page to load still slowly than a lower one which have to reach the image from the server, what is theorically the best choice here ?

Comment: It would be faster to use real images and let the browser cache it than having the extra bytes inpage, let the browser decode the base64 several times and render the image that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

If you load the base64 image in the page 15x then you add about 510,000 bits of data to the total page size. This data has to be transferred from the server to the client and will take just over 0.5 seconds (over a 1mb line) + the propagation delay for the page which will be around 75ms. So the total is around (aprox 500ms + 76ms)  => call it 600ms.

If you include put the image on the Server and reference it from the various parts of the page by URL) It has to transmit around 34,000 bits and once downloaded will pull the image from the local download cache a further 14 times + propagation delay for the image and a propagation delay for the page page. Getting the image from cache takes almost no time typically < 1ms) The overall expected cost on a 1mb line would be roughly (34ms + 76ms + 14ms + 76ms) => about 200ms.

This is a highly simplified view of what happens and a number of factors come into play as a page is loaded. The number of hosts domains, Download threads, Script execution, CSS styling, positioning, paint events, layout events and so on.

You can put base64 strings directly in the background: url() CSS tage if its going to be used behind a DIV or button and repated on you page.

But its typically a good thing to put the resource on the server and download it as required by URL in the places its needed. Not only for your sanity when it come time to copy and paste 15 Base64 string into your page when the image changes :)

Comment: Using Javascript, I think you can append the same (base64)DOM node several times into the document - you only copy 1 base64 string into the page, the browser only loads 1 base64 string. This way it might come to about the same speed as a real image with url. Still not a benefit I think.